# Listview redirecting pages

Tags: android-studio

I have a listview with 3 items ("1", "2" and "3"),  I'd like make then clickable and, when I click on 1 to be redirected to the Activity 1, when I click on 2 to the Activity 2 and so on.

That's the UserslistActivity.class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class UsersListActivity extends Activity {

    String[] numbers = {"1","2","3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, numbers);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

That's activity_listview.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#25383C">
</TextView>
```

In the activity_users_list.xml I put only:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set `OnItemClickListener` check the selected item and start desired activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              String selectedItem = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

              if (selectedItem.equals("1")) 
                 startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity1.class));

              //..

              }

            }
        });
```

Comment: should I put that inside the method OnCreate immediately after listView.setAdapter(adapter);? I have in this case only the problem that context was't initialized, should I use getApplicationContext instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's how I changed the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class UsersListActivity extends Activity {

    String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, numbers);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Context context = this;

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (selectedItem.equals("1"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, 1.class));
                else if (selectedItem.equals("2"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, 2.class));
                else if (selectedItem.equals("3"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, 3.class));
                else if (selectedItem.equals("4"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, 4.class));

            }
        });

        }

    }
```

Obviously I created the 4 classes too with the reference to the xml file.

1. class is:

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   public class 1 extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
   }
   ```

   }

and activity_one is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is page one"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

the same is for the other 3 pages, but the app stops after I click on one of them, is there something wrong?

Comment: Ok I solved, I forgot to declare the new activities in android manifest. Thank you for your help!!!